# Can't sync chaquopy version in android gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, chaquopy

I am trying to run python using [chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/) in android and I want to use [latest version](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/versions.html#version-summary) but the gradle is not syncing successfully. I am using `gradle 8.0` for the project.

Note: `Chaquopy 14.0` is also not syncing but `chaquopy 13.0` is syncing :/

I am getting the following error:

```
Build file 'D:\RunPython\build.gradle' line: 5

Plugin [id: 'com.chaquo.python', version: '15.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.chaquo.python', version: '15.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.chaquo.python:com.chaquo.python.gradle.plugin:15.0.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    maven(https://chaquo.com/maven)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 15.0.0 was never released on Maven Central. The current version is 15.0.1, and you can check the released versions [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.chaquo.python/gradle).